General questions about generators of algebras
Basically, I have 2 basic algebraic questions:

If I have given an algebra, f.e. a specific finite-dimensional C$^*$-algebra, what can I state as necessary conditions on a generating set $G$ of this algebra?
If I have given a generating set $L$ of a finite-dimensional Lie-algebra and a CPTP map $T$, what can be said about the image and kernel of T acting on $L$?

I would also be very happy about books and papers where these questions on generating sets and maps on generating sets are dealt with. I was unable to find adequate sources for this.
Thank you in advance.

Those questions are incredibly vague. First, ask only one question per post. Second, please be a lot more precise about the kind of answer you are expecting.
